# Installing a package doesn’t show in my package.json file

Tags: node.js, package

I have a weird problem when I install a Node.js package:

```
npm i socket.io
```

It doesn't appear in my *package.json* file as a dependency, but it was installed and I can use it. The problem is, when someone will download it from GitHub, he/she needs to install *socket.io* manually instead from just npm i. How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
npm i --save socket.io
```

The **--save** option will add the package to your dependencies.